# Incorrect View Functon Return Type in elm

Tags: elm

I am making a program that changes the rendered text on the screen to be whatever the user inputs in a text box. I think I have the model and the update part of the elm architecture correct, but I really don't understand the view portion.

I'm just having trouble wrapping my head around the square bracket view functions.

Anyway, I am getting this error.

This `div` call produces:

```
Html #(Model -> Model)#
```

But the type annotation on `view` says it should be:

```
Html #Msg#Elm
```

But I am not sure how to change my view function to return Html Msg and I am kinda confused between the difference between that and a string.

Thank you everyone!

Here is my code ...

```
module Main exposing (..)

import Browser
import Html exposing (Html, div, text, input, Attribute)
import Html.Attributes exposing (..)
import Html.Events exposing (onInput)

main =
  Browser.sandbox { init = init, update = update, view = view }

type alias Model = String

init : Model
init = "Hello, World!"

type alias Msg = String

update : Msg -> Model -> Model
update msg model =
  msg

view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
  div []
    [ input [ placeholder "Input new string", value model, onInput update ] []
    , div [] [ text model ]
    ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing the `update` function as an argument to onInput. Your probably meant to pass it a Msg, which the runtime will then pass to the update function.

Since your Msg type is an alias for String, you can use `onInput identity`

Comment: Thank you! What is identity?

Comment: `identity` is the identity function https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/core/latest/Basics#identity